# Command on Linux to tell is displayport over USB-C is supported

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device

I am running Linux and kernel 5.3 which has apparently had the DP Altmode supported for some time, but cannot get a monitor to work from an adapter cable.

Question:  what is a shell command that will tell me If I can expect the hardware and software to support DP Altmode over USB-C on this machine?